# Customizer Parent Theme Property Overwrite

Tags: wordpress

is it possible to insert extra properties from child theme to parent theme existing customizer options?

suppose there is color section in parent theme
I want to add extra color options from child theme to same color section of Parent theme. Any Ideas?